# What is the maximum size of upload file we can receive in FastAPI?

Tags: python, http, backend, server-side, fastapi

I am trying to figure out the maximum file size, my client can upload , so that my python fastapi server can handle it without any problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no actual limit: https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/890 - see https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/362 for how to implement a limit based on the `Content-Length` header

Comment: thanks for answering, aren't there any http payload size limitations also?

Comment: If you're thinking of POST size, that's discussed in those tickets - but it would depend on whether you're serving requests through FastAPI/Starlette directly on the web, or if it goes through nginx or similar first. Any part of the chain may introduce limitations on the size allowed.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) on how to read the request body in chunks using [`.stream()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/requests.py#L208), and hence, enforce body/file size limits in your application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your request doesn't reach the ASGI app directly. It goes through reverse proxy (Nginx, Apache), ASGI server (uvicorn, hypercorn, gunicorn) before handled by an ASGI app.

#### Reverse Proxy

For Nginx, the body size is controlled by `client_max_body_size`, which defaults to 1MB.

For Apache, the body size could be controlled by `LimitRequestBody`, which defaults to 0.

#### ASGI Server

The ASGI servers don't have a limit of the body size. At least it's the case for gunicorn, uvicorn, hypercorn.

Quote from Hypercorn doc.

> Large request body
>
> This attack is of the second type and aims to exhaust the server’s memory by inviting it to receive a large request body (and hence write the body to memory). A poorly configured server would have no limit on the request body size and potentially allow a single request to exhaust the server.
>
> It is **up to the framework to guard against this attack**. This is to allow the framework to consume the request body if desired.

Note: Gunicorn doesn't limit the size of request body, but sizes of the request line and request header.

- `--limit-request-line`, size limit on each req line, default 4096
- `--limit-request-fields`, number of header fields, default 100
- `--limit-request-field_size`, size of headef fields, default 8190

#### ASGI App/Framework

Since FastAPI is based upon Starlette. How to reading the body is handled by Starlette. Reading from the source (0.14.3), there seems no limit on request body either.

```py
class Request(HTTPConnection):
    ...
    async def stream(self) -> typing.AsyncGenerator[bytes, None]:
        if hasattr(self, "_body"):
            yield self._body
            yield b""
            return

        if self._stream_consumed:
            raise RuntimeError("Stream consumed")

        self._stream_consumed = True
        while True:
            message = await self._receive()
            if message["type"] == "http.request":
                body = message.get("body", b"")
                if body:
                    yield body
                if not message.get("more_body", False):
                    break
            elif message["type"] == "http.disconnect":
                self._is_disconnected = True
                raise ClientDisconnect()
        yield b""

    async def body(self) -> bytes:
        if not hasattr(self, "_body"):
            chunks = []
            async for chunk in self.stream():
                chunks.append(chunk)
            self._body = b"".join(chunks)
        return self._body
```

---

**Conclusion**: If you get **413 Payload Too Large** error, check the reverse proxy.