# How to Upload a large File (≥3GB) to FastAPI backend?

Tags: python, file-upload, fastapi, starlette, python-requests-toolbelt

I am trying to upload a large file (≥3GB) to my FastAPI server, **without** loading the entire file into memory, as my server has only 2GB of free memory.

**Server side**:

```
async def uploadfiles(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...):
```

**Client side**:

```
m = MultipartEncoder(fields = {"upload_file":open(file_name,'rb')})
prefix = "http://xxx:5000"
url = "{}/v1/uploadfiles".format(prefix)
try:
    req = requests.post(
    url,
    data=m,
    verify=False,
            )
```

which returns:

```json
HTTP 422 {"detail":[{"loc":["body","upload_file"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

I am not sure what `MultipartEncoder` actually sends to the server, so that the request does not match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With `requests-toolbelt` library, you have to pass the `filename` as well, when declaring the `field` for `upload_file`, as well as **set the `Content-Type` header**—which is the main reason for the error you get, as you are sending the request without setting the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`, followed by the necessary [`boundary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) string—as shown in the [documentation](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html). Example:

```py
filename = 'my_file.txt'
m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'upload_file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb'))})
r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
print(r.request.headers)  # confirm that the 'Content-Type' header has been set
```

However, I wouldn't recommend using a library (i.e., [`requests-toolbelt`](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt)) that hasn't provided a new release for over three years now. I would suggest using Python requests instead, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) (also see [Streaming Uploads and Chunk-Encoded Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads)), or, preferably, use the [`HTTPX`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/) library, which supports `async` requests (if you had to send multiple requests simultaneously), as well as streaming `File` uploads by default, meaning that only one chunk at a time will be loaded into memory (see the [documentation](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#multipart-file-encoding)). Examples are given below.

### Option 1 (Fast) - Upload `File` and `Form` data using `.stream()`

As previously explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804), when you declare an [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) object, FastAPI/Starlette, under the hood, uses a `SpooledTemporaryFile` with the `max_size` attribute set to **1MB**, meaning that the file data is spooled in memory until the file size exceeds the `max_size`, at which point the contents are written to disk; more specifically, to a `temporary` file on your OS's temporary directory—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71377044/17865804) on how to find/change the default temporary directory—that you later need to read the data from, using the `.read()` method. Hence, this whole process makes uploading file quite slow; especially, if it is a large file (as you'll see in Option 2 below later on).

To avoid that and speed up the process, as the linked answer above suggested, one can access the `request` body as a stream. As per [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body), if you use the [`.stream()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/requests.py#L208) method, the (request) byte chunks are provided without storing the entire body to memory (and later to a temporary file, if the body size exceeds 1MB). This method allows you to read and process the byte chunks as they arrive. The below takes the suggested solution a step further, by using the [`streaming-form-data`](https://github.com/siddhantgoel/streaming-form-data) library, which provides a Python parser for parsing streaming `multipart/form-data` input chunks. This means that not only you can upload `Form` data along with `File(s)`, but you also don't have to wait for the entire request body to be received, in order to start parsing the data. The way it's done is that you initialise the main parser class (passing the HTTP request `headers` that help to determine the input `Content-Type`, and hence, the [`boundary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) string used to separate each body part in the multipart payload, etc.), and associate one of the [`Target`](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#target-classes) classes to define what should be done with a field when it has been extracted out of the request body. For instance, [`FileTarget`](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#filetarget) would stream the data to a file on disk, whereas [`ValueTarget`](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#valuetarget) would hold the data in memory (this class can be used for either `Form` or `File` data as well, if you don't need the file(s) saved to the disk). It is also possible to define your own [custom `Target` classes](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#custom-target-classes). I have to mention that [`streaming-form-data`](https://github.com/siddhantgoel/streaming-form-data) library does not currently support `async` calls to I/O operations, meaning that the writing of chunks happens `sync`hronously (within a `def` function). Though, as the endpoint below uses [`.stream()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/requests.py#L208) (which is an `async` function), it will give up control for other tasks/requests to run on the event loop, while waiting for data to become available from the stream. You could also run the function for parsing the received data in a separate thread and `await` it, using Starlette's [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35)—e.g., `await run_in_threadpool(parser.data_received, chunk)`—which is used by FastAPI internally when you call the `async` methods of `UploadFile`, as shown [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/f6ea760a80d8b109fb6afd1c03e9a33754e6bb5f/starlette/datastructures.py#L456). For more details on `def` vs `async def`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804).

You can also perform certain validation tasks, e.g., ensuring that the input size is not exceeding a certain value. This can be done using the [`MaxSizeValidator`](https://github.com/siddhantgoel/streaming-form-data/blob/d900c1f750896e7221d7896aab4ff892b91730a2/streaming_form_data/validators.py#L5). However, as this would only be applied to the fields you defined—and hence, it wouldn't prevent a malicious user from sending extremely large request body, which could result in consuming server resources in a way that the application may end up crashing—the below incorporates a custom `MaxBodySizeValidator` class that is used to make sure that the request body size is not exceeding a pre-defined value. The both validators desribed above solve the problem of limiting upload file (as well as the entire request body) size in a likely better way than the one desribed [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/362#issuecomment-584104025), which uses `UploadFile`, and hence, the file needs to be entirely received and saved to the temporary directory, before performing the check (not to mention that the approach does not take into account the request body size at all)—using as ASGI middleware such as [this](https://github.com/steinnes/content-size-limit-asgi) would be an alternative solution for limiting the request body. Also, in case you are using [Gunicorn with Uvicorn](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/#gunicorn-with-uvicorn-workers), you can also define limits with regards to, for example, the number of HTTP header fields in a request, the size of an HTTP request header field, and so on (see the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=limit#security)). Similar limits can be applied when using reverse proxy servers, such as Nginx (which also allows you to set the maximum request body size using the [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) directive).

A few notes for the example below. Since it uses the `Request` object directly, and not `UploadFile` and `Form` objects, the endpoint won't be properly documented in the auto-generated docs at `/docs` (if that's important for your app at all). This also means that you have to perform some checks yourself, such as whether the required fields for the endpoint were received or not, and if they were in the expected format. For instance, for the `data` field, you could check whether `data.value` is empty or not (empty would mean that the user has either not included that field in the `multipart/form-data`, or sent an empty value), as well as  if `isinstance(data.value, str)`. As for the file(s), you can check whether `file_.multipart_filename` is not empty; however, since a `filename` could likely not be included in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_header_for_a_multipart_body) by some user, you may also want to check if the file exists in the  filesystem, using `os.path.isfile(filepath)` (Note: you need to make sure there is no pre-existing file with the same name in that specified location; otherwise, the aforementioned function would always return `True`, even when the user did not send the file).

Regarding the applied size limits, the `MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE` below must be larger than `MAX_FILE_SIZE` (plus all the `Form` values size) you expcect to receive, as the raw request body (that you get from using the `.stream()` method) includes a few more bytes for the `--boundary` and `Content-Disposition` header for each of the fields in the body. Hence, you should add a few more bytes, depending on the `Form` values and the number of files you expect to receive (hence the `MAX_FILE_SIZE + 1024` below).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException, status
from streaming_form_data import StreamingFormDataParser
from streaming_form_data.targets import FileTarget, ValueTarget
from streaming_form_data.validators import MaxSizeValidator
import streaming_form_data
from starlette.requests import ClientDisconnect
import os

MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 4  # = 4GB
MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE = MAX_FILE_SIZE + 1024

app = FastAPI()

class MaxBodySizeException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, body_len: str):
        self.body_len = body_len

class MaxBodySizeValidator:
    def __init__(self, max_size: int):
        self.body_len = 0
        self.max_size = max_size

    def __call__(self, chunk: bytes):
        self.body_len += len(chunk)
        if self.body_len > self.max_size:
            raise MaxBodySizeException(body_len=self.body_len)
 
@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(request: Request):
    body_validator = MaxBodySizeValidator(MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE)
    filename = request.headers.get('Filename')
    
    if not filename:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, 
            detail='Filename header is missing')
    try:
        filepath = os.path.join('./', os.path.basename(filename)) 
        file_ = FileTarget(filepath, validator=MaxSizeValidator(MAX_FILE_SIZE))
        data = ValueTarget()
        parser = StreamingFormDataParser(headers=request.headers)
        parser.register('file', file_)
        parser.register('data', data)
        
        async for chunk in request.stream():
            body_validator(chunk)
            parser.data_received(chunk)
    except ClientDisconnect:
        print("Client Disconnected")
    except MaxBodySizeException as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE, 
           detail=f'Maximum request body size limit ({MAX_REQUEST_BODY_SIZE} bytes) exceeded ({e.body_len} bytes read)')
    except streaming_form_data.validators.ValidationError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_413_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE, 
            detail=f'Maximum file size limit ({MAX_FILE_SIZE} bytes) exceeded') 
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 
            detail='There was an error uploading the file') 
   
    if not file_.multipart_filename:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, detail='File is missing')

    print(data.value.decode())
    print(file_.multipart_filename)
        
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {filename}"}
```

As mentioned earlier, to upload the data (on client side), you can use the `HTTPX` library, which supports streaming file uploads by default, and thus allows you to send large streams/files without loading them entirely into memory. You can pass additional `Form` data as well, using the `data` argument. Below, a custom header, i.e., `Filename`, is used to pass the filename to the server, so that the server instantiates the `FileTarget` class with that name (you could use the `X-` prefix for custom headers, if you wish; however, it is [not officially recommended anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions)).

**test.py**

```py
import httpx
import time

url ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
files = {'file': open('bigFile.zip', 'rb')}
headers = {'Filename': 'bigFile.zip'}
data = {'data': 'Hello World!'}

with httpx.Client() as client:
    start = time.time()
    r = client.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Time elapsed: {end - start}s')
    print(r.status_code, r.json(), sep=' ')
```

##### Upload Multiple `File`s and `Form` data using `.stream()`

To upload multiple files, use a header for each filename, or use random names on server side, and once the file is fully uploaded, you could optionally rename it to `file_.multipart_filename`, for instance—regardless, in a real-world scenario, you should never trust the filename (or even the file extension) passed by the user, as it might be malicious, trying to extract or replace files in your system, and thus, it is always a good practice to add some random alphanumeric characters at the end/front of the filename, if not using a complete random name, for each file that is uploaded—and pass a list of files, as described in the `httpx`'s [documentation](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#multipart-file-encoding). Note that you should use a different key/field name for each file, so that they don't overlap when parsing them on server side, e.g., `files = [('file0', open('bigFile.zip', 'rb')),('file1', open('otherBigFile.zip', 'rb'))]`. Finally, define the `Target` classes (either `FileTarget` or `ValueTarget`) on server side, accordingly.

You could test the example below, using either the HTML template at `/`, which uses JavaScript to prepare and send the request with multiple files, or the Python `httpx` client provided below.

For simplicity purposes, the example below does not perform validation checks on the body size; however, if you wish, you could still perform those checks using the code provided in the previous example.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from starlette.requests import ClientDisconnect
from urllib.parse import unquote
import streaming_form_data
from streaming_form_data import StreamingFormDataParser
from streaming_form_data.targets import FileTarget, ValueTarget
import os


app = FastAPI()

   
@app.get('/')
async def main():
    content = """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="files" onchange="reset()" multiple><br>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitUsingFetch()">
          <p id="resp"></p>
          <script>
             function reset() {
                var resp = document.getElementById("resp");
                resp.innerHTML = "";
                resp.style.color = "black";
             }
             
             function submitUsingFetch() {
                var resp = document.getElementById("resp");
                var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
                if (fileInput.files[0]) {
                   var formData = new FormData();
                   var headers = new Headers();
                   formData.append("data", "Hello World!");
             
                   var i = 0;
                   for (const file of fileInput.files) {
                      filename = encodeURI(file.name);
                      headers.append(`filename${i}`, filename);
                      formData.append(`file${i}`, file, filename);
                      i++;
                   }
             
                   fetch('/upload', {
                         method: 'POST',
                         headers: headers,
                         body: formData,
                      })
                      .then(response => response.json())
                      .then(data => {
                         resp.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data); // data is a JSON object
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                         console.error(error);
                      });
                } else {
                   resp.innerHTML = "Please choose some file(s)...";
                   resp.style.color = "red";
                }
             }
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)   


@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(request: Request):
    try:
        parser = StreamingFormDataParser(headers=request.headers)
        data = ValueTarget()
        parser.register('data', data)
        
        headers = dict(request.headers)
        filenames = []
        i =0
        while True:
            filename =  headers.get(f'filename{i}', None)
            if filename is None:
                break
            filename = unquote(filename)
            filenames.append(filename)
            filepath = os.path.join('./', os.path.basename(filename)) 
            file_ = FileTarget(filepath)
            parser.register(f'file{i}', file_)
            i += 1
                
        async for chunk in request.stream():
            parser.data_received(chunk)
    except ClientDisconnect:
        print("Client Disconnected")
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 
            detail='There was an error uploading the file') 
    
    print(data.value.decode())
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {filenames}"}
```

**test.py**

```py
import httpx
import time

url ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
headers = {'filename0': 'bigFile.zip', 'filename1': 'otherBigFile.zip'}
files = [('file0', open('bigFile.zip', 'rb')), ('file1', open('otherBigFile.zip', 'rb'))]
data = {'data': 'Hello World!'}

with httpx.Client() as client:
    start = time.time()
    r = client.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Time elapsed: {end - start}s')
    print(r.status_code, r.json(), sep=' ')
```

##### Upload both `File`s and `JSON` body

In case you would like to upload both file(s) and JSON instead of `Form` data, you could use the approach described in Method 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), thus also saving you from performing manual checks on the received `Form` fields, as explained earlier (see the linked answer for more details). To that end, please make the following changes in the code above. For an HTML/JS example, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).

**app.py**

```py
#...
from fastapi import Form
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from typing import Optional
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

#...

class Base(BaseModel):
    name: str
    point: Optional[float] = None
    is_accepted: Optional[bool] = False
  
def checker(data: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        return Base.parse_raw(data)
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise HTTPException(detail=jsonable_encoder(e.errors()), status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
        

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(request: Request):
    #...
    
    # place the below after the try-except block in the example given earlier
    model = checker(data.value.decode())
    print(dict(model))
```

**test.py**

```py
#...
import json

data = {'data': json.dumps({"name": "foo", "point": 0.13, "is_accepted": False})}
#...
```

### Option 2 (Slow) - Upload `File` and `Form` data using `UploadFile` and `Form`

If you would like to use a normal `def` endpoint instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi/70657621#70657621).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Form, HTTPException, status
import aiofiles
import os

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024  # adjust the chunk size as desired
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...), data: str = Form(...)):
    try:
        filepath = os.path.join('./', os.path.basename(file.filename))
        async with aiofiles.open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            while chunk := await file.read(CHUNK_SIZE):
                await f.write(chunk)
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, 
            detail='There was an error uploading the file')
    finally:
        await file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

As mentioned earlier, using this option would take longer for the file upload to complete, and as `HTTPX` uses a default timeout of 5 seconds, you will most likely get a `ReadTimeout` exception (as the server will need some time to read the `SpooledTemporaryFile` in chunks and write the contents to a permanent location on the disk). Thus, you can [configure the timeout](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#timeout-configuration) (see the [`Timeout`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/9baf3a6cd2fa9ebeb17dba5a3e5c6e9e0af83a96/httpx/_config.py#L189) class in the source code too), and more specifically, the `read` timeout, which "specifies the maximum duration to wait for a chunk of data to be received (for example, a chunk of the response body)". If set to `None` instead of some positive numerical value, there will be no timeout on `read`.

**test.py**

```py
import httpx
import time

url ='http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
files = {'file': open('bigFile.zip', 'rb')}
headers = {'Filename': 'bigFile.zip'}
data = {'data': 'Hello World!'}
timeout = httpx.Timeout(None, read=180.0)

with httpx.Client(timeout=timeout) as client:
    start = time.time()
    r = client.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Time elapsed: {end - start}s')
    print(r.status_code, r.json(), sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, and the reason I use this library is that I found somewhere saying it could help dealing with large files upload. And I just tried to upload a 3GB file using requests and encountered memory error(server only has a free memory of 2G). Are there any choices to implement this feature?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to read the file in chunks on server side, hence avoiding loading the entire file into memory. The `requests-toolbelt` lib allows you to avoid loading the entire file into memory before being sent to the server (i.e., on client side). The equivalent of that in `requests` lib is [Streaming uploads or Chunk-Encoded Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads).

Comment: As I used the streaming uploads, I put file as f into the data, along with other element. 
so finally it looks like
data={'a':'2','b':'3','file':file}
req = requests.post(url, data=data)
and I got error422 value is not a dict. But I cannot do json.dumps(data) because it contains a file. How to fix it

Comment: maybe using with open() simply applied the upload streaming? I;m not sure about that

Comment: Please have a look above.

Comment: In app.py, how can I modified the file_path using the file_path sent in request data? I tried  await request.form() but it seemed to consume the stream and led to an error

Comment: The parser parses the data as they arrive, and this is what makes it fast. Using `await request.form()` would simply consume the stream, as you noticed, and parse the whole body in the end (which would be the same as using Option 2). Since the data get parsed as they are streaming, and since we had to pre-define the `filapath` for the `FileTarget()` class, the `filename` header sent by the client is used for this purpose (you can set the value of `filename` header as desired). You could also use `os.rename()` at the end of the stream, to rename the file using `file_.multipart_filename`.

Comment: Why would Option 1 not run into the default timeout of 5s?

Comment: Can you please give an example of "finally, define the Target classes on server side accordingly" for multiple file uploads? Not sure how to do this properly.

Comment: @nb123 The answer above has been updated with a relevant example on how to upload multiple files and form data, using the *fast* approach. Please have a look.

Comment: @Chris thank you so much! As an extension of my previous qn - how do you validate the ContentType of the file when reading in a stream? If there is no direct way, what is the security best practice to ensure you only accept a particular file extension (eg: .pdf)?

Comment: @nb123 You could simply check a file's extension by extracting the extension part from the `filename` that is sent in the `headers` (using the examples of Option 1 above). Alternatively (or, in addition to that), you could use `python-magic` library - please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73672334/17865804), under **MIME Type** section, for more details.