# Facing slow video upload to database via Fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am making a website which accepts video and then the video is converted into `bytes` and then I store it in database after converting with `io.BytesIO()` function.
It took me a long time *(approx. 20-30sec)* for just saving a 30 sec video *(approx. 18-20mb video file)*.

I am using Deta Drive for database for saving the videos which is a *non-asynchronous*.

> ***Note : I want to save the videos in database only not in file.***

**My Code**

app.py

```
@app.post("", response_description="Post data added into the database")
async def create_post(data: PostsSchema = Depends(), video: UploadFile = File(default=None), background_tasks: BackgroundTasks = BackgroundTasks()):
    data = data.dict()
    
    if not video:
        video_data = None
    else:
        video.filename = f"{data['postid']}.mp4"
        video_contents = await video.read()

    data = jsonable_encoder(data)
    
    data["created_at"] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
    data["video"] = video_data

    background_tasks.add_task(add_post, post_data=data)
    
    return ResponseModel('Success', 'Post created!')
```

database.py

```
video_database = deta.Drive("video")


async def add_post(post_data : dict):
    if post_data["is_video_post"]:
        post = video_database.put(name='some_name.mp4', data=io.BytesIO(post_data["video"]), content_type="video/mp4")

    post = await post_database.put(data=post_data, key=some_key)
    new_post = await post_database.get(key=some_key)
    return post_helper(new_post)
```

Please help me with this problem...

*I am expecting it to be fast as much as possible.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upload a large File (≥3GB) to FastAPI backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73442335/how-to-upload-a-large-file-%e2%89%a53gb-to-fastapi-backend)

Comment: @Chris No, as It is saving in `file` rather than I want it to send to `database`!