# How to fileupload in fastapi without using python-multipart

Tags: fastapi

How to fileupload in fastapi of file passed from the angular without using python-multipart and How to pass the file data from angular and upload in a destination folder in fastapi python without using python-multipart ?

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) as well