# Persistent 422 Error with FastApi with an endpoint that accepts parameters and a file upload

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint defined for uploading a file, and accepting some parameters. Through the swagger interface this endpoint works perfectly. My 3 parameters are saved to my database, and my file is uploaded. However, creating a test, to try and replicate posting to this endpoint a file, and 3 parameters, results in FastAPI returning a 422 error with

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}.
```

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure where I'm going wrong.

**Parameter Model**

```
class PcapCreate(BaseModel):
    """
    API schema for posting a new file.
    """

    test_run_id: uuid.UUID
    component_id: uuid.UUID
    pcap_create_user: uuid.UUID
```

**Endpoint**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, status, File, UploadFile, Depends
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

from core.responses import APIResponse
from models.pcaps import Pcaps
from models.pcapcreate import PcapCreate
from models.ack import ACK
from models.nack import NACK

@router.post(
    "/",
    summary="upload a new pcap file",
    description="Uploads a new pcap file.",
    response_model=ACK,
    name="pcaps:create-pcap",
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    responses={404: {"model": NACK}},
)
async def upload_pcap(
        pcap: PcapCreate = Depends(),
        file: UploadFile = File(...),
) -> JSONResponse:
    """
    Endpoint view for uploading a new file.
    """
    instance = await Pcaps(**pcap.dict(exclude_unset=True)).save()

    pcap_id = str(instance.pcap_id)

    ... code for saving file to disk.

    success_text: str = "success"
    ack_message: dict = APIResponse.ack(pcap_id, success_text)

    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content=ack_message
    )
```

**My Test**

```
import pytest
from fastapi import FastAPI, status
from httpx import AsyncClient

async def test_endpoint_create_valid_pcap_201(
    app: FastAPI,
    client: AsyncClient,
) -> None:
    """
    Tests if a POST request with a file upload returns a 201 response.
    """
    files = {
        'file': open('tests/test.pcap', 'rb'),
    }
    params = {
        "test_run_id": "e3db3e6d-f3db-4d9a-8db5-9ee3e3396ff9",
        "component_id": "d060307d-8b84-44b4-848d-4bd910219d92",
        "pcap_create_user": "6f3300ac-d478-4aa1-8316-c6f30b8402ce",
    }

    response = await client.post(
        app.url_path_for("pcaps:create-pcap"),
        params=params,
        files=files
    )
    print(response.url)
    print(response.text)
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks both.  I've actually implemented method 2 from your suggestions but it doesn't work. The only difference is that I'm using httpx, where as the suggestions given are using the requests library.  Maybe httpx is not forming the request properly - don't know.