# How to upload file and json to fastapi from httpx?

Tags: fastapi

Following the [fastapi docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/) on the subject I have:

```
@app.post("/api/files")
async def create_file(
    fileb: Annotated[UploadFile, File()],
    token: Annotated[str, Form()],
):
    return {
        "token": token,
        "fileb_content_type": fileb.content_type,
    }
```

and then with httpx I can do:

```
resp=httpx.post(
    "http://localhost:7071/api/files",
    files={'fileb': open('function.json','rb')},
    data={'token':'fff'},
    )
```

This works but, in my real application, I want to receive json.

httpx won't take a nested dict for `data` so I do...

```
resp=httpx.post(
    "http://localhost:7071/api/files",
    files={'fileb': open('function.json','rb')},
    data={'token':json.dumps({'y':'abc'}),
    )
```

so then in my fastapi function I seemingly need to do something like

```
try:
    token = Params(**json.loads(token))
except Exception as err:
    return Response(f"Failed with {err}", 422)
```

where `Params` is the pydantic BaseModel class I declare.

I kind of rubber ducked my way this far so I'm happy it works at all but it seems off.

Is that the proper way to do it or am I missing something?

Is there a way to get my `Params` model in the parameter part of my fastapi function?

Is there a way in httpx post where I don't have to call `json.dumps`, either by changing the fastapi setup or changing the `httpx.post` request?

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) helpful as well.